# Syntax Error 'Cat' Unexpected

Tags: android, shell

I wrote this script for copying XML files I received to a spot on my sdcard. However when I run it in terminal i get the following. Can someone explain if i did something wrong or whats going on?

- cd /data/com.idv.android/cache/receivedxml/
- /data/xml.sh[4]: cd: /data/com.idv.android/: No such file or directory
- /data/xml.sh[7]: syntax error: 'cat' unexpected

Additional info: Samsung Galaxy S2 Skyrocket / Rooted /

```
#!/system/bin/sh
set -x verbose

cd /data/data/com.idv.android/cache/receivedxml/
if ls *.xml &> /dev/null; then
  for file in *.xml
  do
    cat "$file" > "/storage/sdcard0/XMLList/${file}"
  done
fi
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

cp and cat is not support by original android system. try install a busybox.

and, cd /data/*/ need root privilege.

Comment: I do have busybox installed. :/

Comment: try 'busybox cp' intead of 'cp', 'busybox cat' instead of 'cat'.

Comment: If I change the header to #!/System/xbin and run it i get /data/xml.sh: permission denied

Comment: su -c 'sh xml.sh'?

Comment: Get back permission denied on that also.

Comment: deny execute script or?

Comment: Permission denied on su -c /data/xml.sh

Comment: su -c 'sh /data/xml.sh', use 'sh' manually.

Comment: i get `+ cd /data/com/idv/android/cache/receivedxml`    `:No such file or directorydata/com.idv.android/cache/receivedxml`    `/data/xml.sh[7]: syntax error: 'cp' unexpected/` @afpro

Comment: su -c 'for file in \`ls /data/data/com.idv.android/cache/receivedxml/*.xml 2>/dev/null\`; do busybox cp "/data/data/com.idv.android/cache/receivedxml/$file" "/storage/sdcard0/XMLList/$file"; done'

Comment: I hope you meant for me to type that entire thing out in terminal. :) here is what I got. **sh: can't create /dev/null; do busybox cp "/data/data/com.idv.android/cache/receivedxml/$file" "/storage/sdcard0/XMLList"; done: No such file or directory**

Comment: +1 for technical support, beyond the call of duty. Good luck to all.

Comment: that command works fine on my phone, i have no idea what happened to you now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell may not be support things method: `&> /dev/null`. I think you can only do that in bash.

Try converting your line to:

```
if ls *.xml > /dev/null 2>&1; then
```

Also, just in case but try not to add leading spaces to your header:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

Comment: I put in both of the suggestions eg 2>*1; and using cp instead of cat and i still get the same results except syntax error: 'cp' unexpected.

Comment: @IDV The script looks really fine. Try to check if you're saving it as DOS format instead. Run `dos2unix script.sh`.

Comment: after I did this and ran it everything seemed fine, as in no messages came up, however it did not copy any files. I'm using cat btw.

Comment: @IDV Did you check /storage/sdcard0/XMLList/? Also, make sure that *.xml do exist. Were there no messages shown even debug messages? Did you see your code going for the `for` loop?

Comment: @konesolebox I checked /storage/sdcard0/XMLList and nothing was there. :/ There are 10+ .xml files. No messages were shown. I type in su /data/xml.sh and it just acts like you are ready to input a new command.

Answer (score -2):

hash_config {
algorithm: SCRYPT,
base64_signer_key: 5BUuLHgCoYKEaPlKtGEqvmjhvha/JTIZH7wsb5IH2jgJRGPyce5YWeaXM/d3AGFdSjl6ubDZmD9XDIudpQRBkA==,
base64_salt_separator: Bw==,
rounds: 8,
mem_cost: 14,
}